# When does the Express req.query variable get different types

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I noticed that the type of query parameters in req.query is

```
string | string[] | QueryString.ParsedQS | QueryString.ParsedQS[]
```

but so far, whenever i used req.query i always got strings.

My questions are

1. What is the QueryString.ParsedQS type?
2. When will the parameter be an array?
3. When will the parameter be a QueryString.ParsedQS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `string | string[] | QueryString.ParsedQS | QueryString.ParsedQS[]` is the type returned by `qs.parse()` method, take a look here at the declaration file: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/qs/index.d.ts#L57.

Take a look at the qs documentation for possible return values of `qs.parse()`:
https://github.com/ljharb/qs

For `req.query` to be parsed from string to object you need to call express `app.set('query parser', 'extended')`, extended is the default value but you may have changed it in your code:
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set